# MongoDB and PHP - Out of memory

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I know, that there are a couple of articles about mongodb and memory, but non of these could help me.

I have a quite big database of around 40GB. My server is a Ubuntu 16.04 with 32GB RAM and a ssd disk.

Now, I get the following messages when I try to insert a new document:

```
MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException [ Error ]:
file /var/lib/mongodb/databasename.35 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
```

And in logfiles I found this:

```
2017-07-25T18:20:58.154+0200 I NETWORK  [conn22] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:46124 conn22: { driver: { name: "mongoc / ext-mongodb:PHP", version: "1.5.5 / 1.2.9" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", version: "16.04", architecture: "x86_64" }, platform: "cfg=0x30c9 posix=200809 stdc=201112 CC=GCC 5.4.0 20160609 CFLAGS="-g -O2" LDFLAGS="" / PHP 5.6.30" }
2017-07-25T18:20:58.189+0200 E CONTROL  [conn22] mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)
2017-07-25T18:20:58.189+0200 I -        [conn22] Assertion: 13636:file /var/lib/mongodb/database_name.35 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information) src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/durable_mapped_file.cpp 271
2017-07-25T18:20:58.205+0200 I CONTROL  [conn22]
```

I have enough diskspace:

```
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop42094p1  799G  299G  468G  40% /
devtmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs               16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               16G  578M   16G   4% /run
tmpfs              5.0M   20K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs               16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
```

And I think memory as well:

```
free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32768        1235        7659         840       23873       31268
Swap:          1024         945          78
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: probably not what you want to hear but you could try a hosting service like Object Rocket. This seems like the kind of issue that requires getting down in the weeds and inner workings of MongoDB

Comment: I already though about. But since the Database is quite huge, it would be very expensive. And the other point is, that my customer don't want to give the data outside the EU, because of the US "all your data belong to us" policy.

Comment: I don't think that's the policy of any data storage companies except google. Interesting perception though

Comment: Not of the companies, but of the patriot act. But I didn't want to start a political discussion (wrong place). The main point is also the price. I 50GB hdd and 16GB ram storage will cost around 1000€ pM. While our current server with 400GB SSD and 32 GB Ram only costs 70€ pM. Thats a hughe difference.

Comment: Agreed on the price... but if you think having a foreign server excludes you from US govt survellance, well I doubt it

Comment: It appears that you are using the MMAPv1 storage engine. What is your MongoDB version, and have you considered using the WiredTiger storage engine? Also please check that your deployment follows the recommendations in the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/) and [UNIX ulimit settings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/)

Comment: I have version 3.4.4. Now switched to wired tiger and atm it works again